# Rotate line by specified angle (Java/ Android)

Tags: java, android, math

this is a more math related question.
In my android app I have a canvas that draws a line from start to endpoint.

I also have an `angle` attribute to rotate the line.

I tried to apply the code bellow to my cocept, but it jumps around weirdly, not pointing in the direction it is supposed to. (0deg = horizontal line)

```
//Coordinates for P1 and P2
int startx = 0;
int starty = 66;
int endx = 420;
int endy = 66;

//Alpha
float angle = 0.000F;
final float radius = 209.500F;
final float extra_radius = 20.000F; //required later - don't mind it

private void reCal(float[] vals) {
    float xAcc = vals[0]*(-1);
    float yAcc = vals[1]*(-1);

    angle = yAcc / 10.000F * 90.000F;
    final float rRadius = radius + extra_radius;
    startx = (int) (radius - Math.cos(angle) * rRadius); //left
    endx = (int) (radius + Math.cos(angle) * rRadius); //right
    starty = 66 + (int) (Math.sin(angle) * rRadius); //top
    endy = 66 - (int) (Math.sin(angle) * rRadius); //bot
}
```

Are their any type conversions that might cause this, or is my math wrong?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I looked at `Math.cos(angle)` and `Math.sin(angle)` at runtime.
They jump around between 0 and 1, even if `angle` is only changed by a little amount.

Now I am wondering: DO THE METHODS TAKE RAD OR DEG AS PARAMETER? (I need deg, obviously)

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? if you want to rotate a vector use one of `Matrix.mapVectors` method

Comment: `startx = (int) (radius - Math.cos(angle) * rRadius);` why `radius` is here?

Comment: @pskink: I use `canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);` - I don't know about the `Matrix`-class or the actual math behind it. I just want to rotate the line around it's center.         @Danil Gaponov: `radius` also functions as the offset from the left in this case (similar to the number 66 for `starty` and `endy`.

Comment: so if you don't want to use Matrix api use `Canvas.rotate()` method

Comment: @pskink: Sound's interessting, but I do not want to rotate everything on my canvas - just this one element.

Comment: so do: canvas.save(); canvas.rotate(angle, cx, cy); canvas.drawLine(cx, cy, cx + dx, cy, paint); canvas.restore();

Comment: Math funcs take Radians, u can use Math.toDegrees()

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for! @pskink: Works perfekt! I'll go with it! Thank you very much guys! Please repost as answer so I can upvote and accept it! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to rotate a line starting at `[cx, cy]` and length of `dx`, use that code snippet:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(angle, cx, cy);
canvas.drawLine(cx, cy, cx + dx, cy, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: How to calculate "dx" so that the line hits the walls of the canvas and there is reflection?
In this case "dx" cannot be a fixed value